# How can I simplify this jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following jquery which I want to simplify.

I am just repeating the same things.

Could anyone give me suggestions please.

Thanks in advance.

```
$("a[rel='imagebox-all']").colorbox({slideshow:true});
$("a[rel='imagebox-new']").colorbox({slideshow:true});
$("a[rel='imagebox-even']").colorbox({slideshow:true});
$("a[rel='imagebox-amina']").colorbox({slideshow:true});
$("a[rel='imagebox-cumulus']").colorbox({slideshow:true});
$("a[rel='imagebox-wee']").colorbox({slideshow:true});
$("a[rel='imagebox-four']").colorbox({slideshow:true});
$("a[rel='imagebox-teen']").colorbox({slideshow:true});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming there are no other values of `imagebox-*` you want to exclude:

```
$("a[rel^='imagebox-']").colorbox({slideshow:true});
```

That being said, attribute selectors are usually best avoided and you're typically better off restructuring your problem to allow a better solution. Like you could use classes:

```
<a href="..." class="imagebox teen"> ...
```

Note the space: that's two classes assigned. So you can do:

```
$("a.imagebox")...
```

for all of them. Or:

```
$("a.imagebox.teen")...
```

for just one of them.

Remember as well you can add multiple selectors with a comma:

```
$("a.class1, a.class2")...
```

will apply what you're doing to anchors with class1 OR class2 versus:

```
$("a.class1.class2")...
```

which applies whatever you're doing to anchors that have class1 AND class2.

Answer (score 3):

You can user the [attributeStartsWith](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue) selector which matches elements that have the specified attribute and it starts with a certain value.

```
$("a[rel^='imagebox-']").colorbox({slideshow:true});
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use

```
$("a[rel^='imagebox']").colorbox({slideshow:true});
```

which applies to any a tag with a rel attribute that starts with imagebox?

Answer (score 1):

Remember to have it structured at least, like this.

```
$("a[rel='imagebox-all']")
.colorbox({
slideshow: !0
}), $("a[rel='imagebox-new']")
.colorbox({
slideshow: !0
}), $("a[rel='imagebox-even']")
.colorbox({
slideshow: !0
}), $("a[rel='imagebox-amina']")
.colorbox({
slideshow: !0
}), $("a[rel='imagebox-cumulus']")
.colorbox({
slideshow: !0
}), $("a[rel='imagebox-wee']")
.colorbox({
slideshow: !0
}), $("a[rel='imagebox-four']")
.colorbox({
slideshow: !0
}), $("a[rel='imagebox-teen']")
.colorbox({
slideshow: !0
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var selectors = [
    "a[rel='imagebox-all']",
    "a[rel='imagebox-new']",
    "a[rel='imagebox-even']",
    // ...
];

$.each(selectors, function(){
    $(this).colorbox({slideshow:true});
});
```

Then, whenever you need to add a new selector, just add it to the selectors array.